# Python3.6 Idle problem

Tags: command-line, python, idle-python

I have a problem with python3.6 idle. I think I installed some package in the past and since then I have a problem installing other problems because whatever I try to install it shows me the same error, even if I try to unistall python it shows me this:

```
idle : Depends: idle-python3.6 but it is not going to be installed
```

I've tried to unistall python but I got this error.
What should I do???

Comment: What happens when you do `sudo apt-get install -f`?  Note also that in my opinion there's better IDEs than IDLE.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using? What is the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: when I do sudo apt-get -f install it shows me this: Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/idle-python3.6_3.6.7-1~18.04_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: The output of cat /etc/apt/sources.list is  :                                                              # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170801)]/ xenial main restricted

Comment: Just a single line? You need to restore repository information in that case. See [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04, I installed this package via cmd `sudo apt install idle-python3.6`.

Comment: It doesen't work , if I try to install with `sudo apt install idle-python3.6` I get this error Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/idle-python3.6_3.6.8-1~18.04.york0_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)